# How to keep the aspect ratio of a foreground image?

Tags: java, android, foreground

I currently have a FrameLayout with a background and a foreground image. The foreground image has transparency using alpha in order to see through and watch the background below.

The foreground image needs to mantain the same aspect ratio of the original bitmap because consists of a trasparent circle in a black screen, much like a spyglass effect. I'm looking for any resolution compatibility.

Unfortunately, I am incapable of achieve this and the foreground shows always its circle stretched.

This is part of the **XML** code:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:foreground="@drawable/foreground"
    android:foregroundGravity="center|fill_horizontal"
>
```

I am also trying to solve my issue providing two diferent images, one with 4:3 ratio and the other with 16:9 ratio, each one in a different drawable folder with the **long** and **notlong** qualifiers.

```
/drawable-long/foreground.png (16:9 aspect)

/drawable-notlong/foreground.png (4:3 aspect)
```

Still with no success.

Do you have any idea of how to get this effect?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can change the scale type of either the foreground or the background. What I would recommend is to either:

1. Place an extra `ImageView` in your `FrameLayout` to serve as your background, and use the `src` and `scaleType` attributes to handle the image and how it scales.
2. Since it's a simple black background with just a transparent circle, you could convert that into a 9-patch, making sure to stretch it evenly around the circle. The circle will not scale, but the black area will extend to fill the view.

Number 1 is my personal recommendation if the circle needs to scale as well.

Comment: Seems like I am unable of using ImageView as a foreground for the full screen and I am not really concerned of the background. I will try the 9-patch way and tell how it goes.

Comment: Why are you unable to do the first one? Just place it as the last item in your FrameLayout and it will appear on top of all of your other views.

Comment: Using a new ImageView as the last item of the FrameLayout is how it is solved. Thank you very much for your help. I appreciate it.

Answer (score 5):

Change this attribute in your FrameLayout:

```
android:foregroundGravity="center"
```

This will place the foreground drawable in the center of the FrameLayout, not changing its size.

`"center|fill_horizontal"` will place it in the center and *stretch* its width to fill the FrameLayout width, which is clearly not what you want.

Comment: The problem with that is I have the same bitmap for all possible resolutions and using only the *center* qualifier will show my foreground image with a small size in the center of the larger resolution screens. I would like the image fitting the screen width and with the same aspect ratio.

Comment: Then, if the foreground image is a circle (and assuming that it is a square drawable), try `center|fill_horizontal|fill_vertical`.

Comment: Being a square drawable makes filling horizontal and vertical to stretch that square and the circle in it to match the screen ratio. Unfortunately, the circle loses its shape.